# How to match a function declaration?

Tags: flex-lexer

In order to match a variable binding you use this:

```
    /* Rules for keywords */
val             { return VAL; }
```

So you put the word val under rules for keywords, what about:

```
fun f x = 5 + x;
```

How do you match the function f?

Answer (score 0):

Given a variable declaration `val x = 42`, the rule you quoted would match the `val` keyword and recognize it as a token of type `VAL`. The rest of the declaration would be matched by other rules. The `x` for example would be matched by a rule for identifiers.

So in order to match the `fun` keyword in `fun f x = 5 + x`, you'd similarly define a rule `fun { return FUN; }` (and add `FUN` to your list of tokens if it isn't already on there). The `f` and `x` would be matched by the same identifier rule that matches the `x` in `val x = 42`.